# COPY Command with comma in string values - Postgresql 10

Tags: database, postgresql, copy, postgresql-10

I am trying to copy the contents of a dat file to a table in PostgreSQL but getting errors. The dat file has the following:

```
1,'"{{text}}","{{NoName}}":"{test},{OneName}:{test}"'
```

Table Schema:

```
Create Table TestInfo (ID int, TestValues text);
```

I run the following query:

```
COPY Test from '/opt/Data/TestInfo.dat' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' NULL AS '';
```

but get the following error

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
```

Even tried

```
COPY Test from '/opt/Data/TestInfo.dat' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' csv;
```

still the same error....
Can some one please help me getting the contents of the dat file copied to the DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because because the default `quote` character for the `copy` command in Postgres is a double quote, and it appears in your csv, it's a single quote instead.

Try this:

```
COPY Test from '/opt/Data/TestInfo.dat' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' QUOTE AS '''' NULL AS '';
```

Note the need to escape the single quote, resulting in 4 single quotes.

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem.